# (Regular) Coulomb wave function

Tags: python, differential-equations, wave-propagation

I'm looking for a way to implement the regular Coulomb wave function in python. This function is a solution to

\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}^2\,u}{\text{d}z^2}+\left(1-\frac{2\eta}{z}-\frac{\ell(\ell+1)}{z^2} \right)u(z)=0
\end{align}

The regular Coulomb wave function is given by

\begin{align}
F_\ell(\eta,z) = C_\ell(\eta)z^{l+1}e^{-iz} \mathstrut_1 F_1(\ell+1-i\eta,2\ell+2,2iz),
\end{align}

which is the function I'm interested in implementing in Python. In a physics context this is Schödinger's equation with a Coulomb potential; $z$ is the radius, $\ell$ is a quantum number and $\eta=Zm\alpha/(\hbar k)$. More specifically I'm interested in implementing the regular Coulomb function for the repulsive interaction with $\ell=1$.

I've looked at [mpmath](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/bessel.html?highlight=coulomb#coulomb-wave-functions) but I'm not sure how to use the `mpf` class with np.array and scipy's curve_fit

Comment: Scipy has the [confluent hypergeometric function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.hyp1f1.html#scipy.special.hyp1f1), is that the main thing you need?

Comment: Unfortunately Scipy's function requires real a,b parameters

Comment: Ah gotcha, sympy has [this function](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/special.html#hypergeometric-functions) which could also work. If efficiency and compatibility with numpy / scipy is important then you can probably [lambdify](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html?highlight=lambdify#module-sympy.utilities.lambdify) it.

Comment: That might work! I will add some context to the question to better explain why I need numpy / scipy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using the integral representation of the regular Coulomb wave function given by
\begin{align}
F_\ell(\eta,\rho) = \frac{\rho^{\ell+1}2^\ell e^{i\rho-(\pi\eta/2)}}{|\Gamma(\ell+1+i\eta)|} \int_0^1 e^{-2i\rho t}t^{\ell+i\eta}(1-t)^{\ell-i\eta} \, \text{d}t
\end{align}
Something like this

```py
    def complex_quadrature(func, a, b, **kwargs):
        def real_func(x):
            return np.real(func(x))
        def imag_func(x):
            return np.imag(func(x))
        real_integral = quad(real_func, a, b, **kwargs)
        imag_integral = quad(imag_func, a, b, **kwargs)
        return (real_integral[0] + 1j*imag_integral[0], real_integral[1:], imag_integral[1:])

    def RegularCoulomb(l,eta,rho):
        First = rho**(l+1)*2**l*np.exp(1j*rho-(np.pi*eta/2),dtype='complex_')/(abs(gamma(l+1+1j*eta)))
        integral = complex_quadrature(lambda t: np.exp(-2*1j*rho*t,dtype='complex_')*t**(l+1j*eta)*(1-t)**(l-1j*eta),0,1)[0]
        return np.array(First*integral,dtype='complex_')

    def C(l,eta):
        return 2**l*np.exp(-np.pi*eta/2)*(abs(gamma(l+1+1j*eta))/(factorial(2*l+1)))
    #Compare to mpmath
    xes = np.linspace(0,10,100)
    coulombfwave = [RegularCoulomb(1,-2,i) for i in xes]

    F1 = lambda x: mpmath.coulombf(1,-2,x)
    mpmath.plot([F1], [0,10])
    plt.plot(xes,coulombfwave)
```